# Почему слетает кодировка на линуксе?

Tags: c#, linux, .net, asp.net

Я написал микросервис, не суть что он делает, - он ведет логи в консоли через Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Микросервис запускается на сервере linux debian, если не ошибаюсь. В проекте прописана cultureInfo и кодировка utf8.
[image: Кодировка]

Есть например строка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли она выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сейчас еще я добавил логирование критических ошибок через телеграм-бота себе в личку, чтобы сразу видеть где проблема - в итоге получаю вот такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде строка выглядит так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гугле инфы нигде не нашел, в чем может быть дело? Кодировка и тд ведь прописана, и локально все хорошо, проблемы появляются именно когда код уходит на линукс.

Comment: А компилируется этот код где? Вернее, вопрос вот в чём: в какой кодировке сохранён файл с кодом?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov глаз-алмаз, очень вероятно, что проблема именно в этом. :) Я что-то не додумался, это кстати объясняет то что `startEndTime` кодируется нормально.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не очень понял если честно, как это посмотреть? А так похоже на правду, потому что в других классах все работает, проблема именно при выводе строк из Program (точка входа)

Comment: Да почти любой мало-мальски продвинутый текстовый редактор показывает кодировку. Открыть и посмотреть. / Visual Studio сохраняет файлы в UTF-8 с BOM. Вот в этой кодировке и сохранять. И перекомпилировать проект.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, это правда. Классы в которых все нормально работает, в UTF8 BOM, а там где кодировка кривая - Character set cyrillic. Как так вышло?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, не знал. Можете в ответы написать, отмечу.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)